# Windows + Xampp + CakePHP - Composer throws error on update

Tags: cakephp, xampp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to create a local development environment on a Windows machine using Xampp. Xampp has been setup correctly and I am able to access `localhost`, `locahost/phpmyadmin` and a virtual host I created `domain.local`. This Virtual Host is a CakePHP application that I had been running on a Linux Box (nginx). I use that code to setup the site, but when I try to run

`php composer.phar update`

to have composer download all dependencies, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Cake\Composer\Installer\PluginInstaller' not found in
phar://C:/Users/admin/Documents/Sites/domain.local/website/composer.phar/src/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php
on line 244
```

I have tried a bunch of things without success.

Also to note `php composer.phar self-update`, runs without issue.

Not sure what to do at this point. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

After more tryouts, I finally decided to delete the `vendor` folder and surprisingly it fixed my issue. Composer downloaded all dependencies and everything works as expected.